# Synonymes de la tournure 'ne rien faire'

Tags: synonymes

Je me demande quelles expressions idiomatiques (ou quels mots) on peut utiliser comme synonymes de 'ne rien faire' (même de façon vulgaire). Une locution que je connais est 'se gratter la fesse/ le cul'. Je connais aussi 'branler' et 'ne rien foutre'.

J'ai consulté le lien ici : [http://www.dictionnaire-synonymes-francophones.fr/definition.php?Id=792#:~:text=Qu%C3%A9bec-,v.,%2C%20fl%C3%A2ner%2C%20tra%C3%AEner%2C%20lambiner](http://www.dictionnaire-synonymes-francophones.fr/definition.php?Id=792#:%7E:text=Qu%C3%A9bec-,v.,%2C%20fl%C3%A2ner%2C%20tra%C3%AEner%2C%20lambiner) mais les mots/tournures proposés ne concernent pas l'Hexagone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Glander, glandouiller
- Buller, coincer la bulle
- Ne rien branler/foutre/fiche(r)
- Ne pas en faire une rame, n'en foutre pas une
- Flemmarder
- Rester les bras croisés
- Tenir le mur

Answer (score 1):

- se tourner les pouces (*seulement familier*)
- se rouler les  pouces (*seulement familier, et
  rare*)
- tourner ses pouces sur son ventre (1833, première attestation)  (*familier ; rare mais la forme initiale*) ([réf.](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/18550))

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=se+rouler+les+pouces%2Cse+tourner+les+pouces&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

- se la couler douce  (*familier,  ne signifie pas « ne rien faire »  mais  seulement  « ne  pas faire  grand  chose »*)

*Autres expressions* ([réf.](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/18550))

- Ne rien faire
- vivre dans l'oisiveté
- être les bras ballants
- les bras croisés
- se croiser les bras
- ne rien faire de ses dix doigts

*Expression presque synonyme*

- se la couler douce  (*familier,  ne signifie pas « ne rien faire »  mais  seulement  « ne  pas faire  grand  chose »*)